# Jenkins svn collabnet build failure

Tags: ssl, jenkins, svn, collabnet

I am getting the below build error :

```
[ERROR] The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w xxxxx.java] failed: svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'xxx-xxxx.java'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

I am using Subversion Edge by Collabnet with jenkins to run the build. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Could anyone please respond to my query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the wording of the error message:

```
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

The error you are getting "Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted" means that there is a problem with the certificate installed on SVN Edge server. The client does not trust the certificate and displays the error. Therefore, you should look into the certificate-related problems on CollabNet Subversion Edge server.

The only possible way to ignore the error is to use [`--trust-server-cert`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.trust_server_cert) command line option. You also have to add [`--non-interactive`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive) option because your CI machine runs the Subversion client non-interactively.

If you use Subversion 1.9 client, you can also use [`--trust-server-cert-failures`](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-trust) option which is intended to ignore a wider range of invalid certificates than [`--trust-server-cert`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.trust_server_cert) that can only ignore certificates issued by unknown or not trusted certificate authority.

Comment: I ran the command svn info --trust-server-cert --non-interactive bit I am getting XXXX(pathname) is not a working copy error. Can you please let me know in which path I nede to run this command or where I have gone wrong.

Comment: The SVN CollabNet version I am using is 1.8.15-4313.35

Comment: error message that its showing specifically is svn: E155007: 'D:\xxxx\xxxx' is not a working copy

Comment: @shwethavr this is another error that's completely unrelated to your question. You do not provide neither URL to the repository to contact nor a local path to the working copy. Just do a little research, please.

Comment: ,Thanks for your response.Can you please help me on where to run that particular command which you shared above:  --trust-server-cert non interactive ..I am a DevOps engineer,responsibility to automate the project configuration in Jenkins.So Please let me know whether that command I can run from the Developers working copy while they are are checking the code into repository if yes,I need that to be automated as I can't run that command everytime with the developers help.Let me know how to automate this command ?

Comment: And please do let me know where exactly i can run/configure this command which you shared.? Much appreciated if you can help me on this quickly.

Comment: @shwethavr ask a new separate question when you have a new question, please. Maybe someone will help you with other issues. I would recommend that you read the docs on Jenkins and SVN.